# How to stream query results using Apache Cassandra

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql

What I would like to do is to make a query against my Cassandra "table" and get not only the current matching data but any future data that's added.

I have an application where data is constantly added to the "table" and I have many "clients" that are interested in getting this data.

So the initial result of the query would be the current data that matches the client's query and then I would like ongoing data to be received as they are added. Each client may be making a different query.

I would prefer to have a callback registered with a query so that I receive the data w/o having to poll.

Is this even possible with Cassandra?

Thank you.

P.S. From my reading, it seems MongoDB does support this feature.

Comment: What language is your application in? Are you using a particular API?

Comment: Using Java for my application.

Comment: Are you using the Hector API? (I don't remember whether there are other options.)

Comment: I have not even chosen a NoSql product yet. I'm investigating capabilities first. So this Hector API might do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Cassandra at present, but the new triggers feature coming in Cassandra 2.0 may do what you need.  It's only going to be experimental when 2.0 comes out (soon).

Comment: Ok thanks. I was reading about Async Triggers and I was thinking, you could setup a trigger when data is added.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does indeed have a feature that might fit the bill.  It's called a ["tailable cursor"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) and can only be used on a capped collection, i.e. a collection that works like a ring buffer and "forgets" old data.  After the tailable cursor has exhausted the entire collection the next read attempt will block until new data becomes available.

You can convert this into a callback pattern easily by implementing a reader thread with which the rest of the application can register its callbacks.